# Django templates, how do I know which template gets called

Tags: python, django, templates

I'm using an external app in my django project which makes use of generic views, and I'm not able to figure out which template gets called for the response.

Do you know how to do that without having to dig into the source code of the app?

May be debugging the stack trace when the template gets loaded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Django debug toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) will tell you.

Answer (score 1):

Use [debug-toolbar](https://github.com/django-debug-toolbar/django-debug-toolbar) when you view a page it will show you the templates used.